# Version Mismatch in React-Native Version 0.60.3

Tags: android, react-native, version

> "react": "16.8.6",
>
> "react-native": "0.60.3"

React Native Version mismatch error after run new vesion app

[image]

Comment: you should try clearing packager and watchman caches by running that command as suggested by that error screen

Answer (score 0):

I have 2 RN projects. And when I use reactotron app with the first project (RN 0.59) and open a new one without stopping reactotron then this error happens. Restarting reactotron helped me.

Answer (score -1):

> react-native **0.60.0** new version

**use the command**

> **react-native start**

**or**

> npm start

**or**

> react-native run-android

Comment: this error in "react-native": "0.60.3" not in "react-native": "0.60.0" versio

Answer (score -1):

**Use this :**

1. First of all uninstall app from your device
2. After this clean gradlew
3. close the Metro bundler and also terminal
4. Open terminal in the root of your project directory and run

> npm start -- --reset-cache

or

> yarn start -- --reset-cache

4. Open another terminal in the root of your project directory and run

> react-native run-android

OR

Restart the system

**Hope it will work**